# How can I add a "cheat code" to this guess a number code I have?

Tags: python-2.7, random, while-loop

I have piece of code below where three numbers are chosen at random and the user has 10 tries to solve the code. I want to add a cheat code (so to say) to allow the user to move on to the next class/function without having to guess the three digit number.

I tried adding an `or guess == 'cheat'` after the `while guess != code and guesses < 10`. I tried taking `if guess == code:` and turning it into `elif guess == code` and adding an `if guess == 'cheat'` before the elif. I'm a noob and the source I'm learning from says my goal can be accomplished with two words on one line. I'm lost…...

```
 code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
 guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")
 guesses = 0

 while guess != code and guesses < 9:
        print "WRONG!"
        guesses += 1
        guess = raw_input("Guess 3 numbers> ")

    if guess == code:
        print "Correct!"
        return my_func()
    else:
        print "Game over"
        return exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure your code is indented correctly. Since you had it working it seems like it's just a formatting issue on the question.

It's a little unclear what this cheat code would be, but I would take it as one of two things: either the word cheat or some other string. Either way it can be stored in a variable called `cheat` and you can quit the while loop when the guess is either `code` or `cheat`.

```
cheat = 'cheat'

while guess not in [code, cheat]:
```

What is also unclear is what should happen when `cheat` is used, there are two possible scenarios:

1. `cheat` ends the game with a lose.

   ```
   code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
   cheat = 'cheat'
   guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")
   guesses = 0

   while guess not in [cheat, code] and guesses < 9:
       print "WRONG!"
       guesses += 1
       guess = raw_input("Guess 3 numbers> ")

   if guess == code:
       print "Correct!"
       return my_func()
   else:
       print "Game over"
       return exit()
   ```
2. `cheat` ends the game in a win.

   ```
   code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
   cheat = 'cheat'
   guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")
   guesses = 0

   while guess not in [cheat, code] and guesses < 9:
       print "WRONG!"
       guesses += 1
       guess = raw_input("Guess 3 numbers> ")

   if guess in [cheat, code]:
       print "Correct!"
       return my_func()
   else:
       print "Game over"
       return exit()
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Number 1 doesn't work, but Number 2 does. Also why brackets around  `in [cheat, code]:` instead of `in (cheat, code):`?

Comment: Square brackets denote a python list and round brackets make it a tuple. Either data structure would work in your case.